# Why is this react component taking ages to re-render, is there a better way of writing this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Im a bit stuck with a current project, its my first big react project so i think there is probably something simple im missing here. I decided to use hooks because it seemed nicer to write, although i had the same issue when i tried to rewrite it with a class component.

Basically i have a page which should display albums of music and links for the songs in those albums, when the links are clicked the link should put a spotify iframe into the DOM. But when the click occurs it takesa long time, sometimes 10 seconds for the difference to appear on the page

code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import FullWidthBanner from './FullWidthBanner';
import Axios from 'axios';

const Song = (props) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <div className={(props.active) ? "songContainer" : "songContainer colourTransition"}>
                <div onClick={() => { props.handleClick(props.name); }} style={{ 'backgroundColor': props.color, "zIndex": (props.active) ? "250" : "300" }} className="songTitle">
                    <h1>{(props.active) ? "LOADING" : props.name}</h1>
                </div>
                {(props.active || props.clickCount) ? <iframe src={props.src} style={{ "zIndex": (props.active) ? "300" : "250" }} width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe> : null}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const Album = (props) => {
    const [songs, setSongs] = useState(props.songs);

    const handleClick = (name) => {
        for (var key in songs) {
            songs[key].active = 0;
        }
        let activeSong = songs.filter((song) => {
            return song.name == name;
        });
        let index = songs.indexOf(activeSong[0]);
        songs[index].active = 1;
        songs[index].clickCount++;
        setSongs(songs);
    }

    return (
        <div className="alContainer">
            {songs.map((song) => {
                return (
                    <Song {...song} handleClick={handleClick} />
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

const AlbumMeta = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="albumMetaContainer">
            <img src={props.artwork} width="200" height="200" alt={"The album artwork for Sam Malcolm's album " + props.name} />
            <div className="infoContainer">
                <h1>{props.name}  <i>{props.year}</i></h1>
                <p>{props.description}</p>
                <div>
                    {(props.spotifyLink) ? <a style={{ 'borderColor': props.highlight }} href={props.spotifyLink} target="_blank" className="smBtn" >View on Spotify</a> : null}
                    {(props.itunesLink) ? <a style={{ 'borderColor': props.highlight }} href={props.itunesLink} target="_blank" className="smBtn" >View on iTunes</a> : null}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const Albums = (props) => {

    const [albums, setAlbums] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get('/api/albums').then((response) => {
            setAlbums(response.data);
        })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="albumsContainer">
            <FullWidthBanner caption="Photo: Joe Bloggs" backgroundPosition="top center" src="/path/to/image.jpg" title="Music" />
            {albums.map((album) => {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <AlbumMeta {...album} highlight={props.highlight} />
                        <Album {...album} />
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}


export default Albums
```

I feel like there is just a better way to write this. Interestingly when I remove the second argument from useEffect, which causes an infinite loop, the page updates immediately when I click, which is weird.

Comment: One thing that may help, at least some, is you should be specifying a `key` on your div in your albums.map. This helps React's vdom reconciliation algorithm know to consider two elements in the same spot the same and not have to tear down/recreate every time a render happens.

Comment: I would recommend not putting long components all on one line - not doing so makes the html block look cleaner, sure, but only if you don't have to read any of the long bits. Being able to see everything at once (i.e., every attribute/parameter of a block on its own line) usual helps when finding bugs and making changes. But aside from that, if you update state in useEffect and cause an infinite loop of updates, it makes sense that any other update would be seen immediately. It updating slowly otherwise is the weird part (jas' comment sounds right though).

Comment: I think it's because you're mutating state. Please have a look in the following [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-chatelet-chde7). If that's your issue then I could add more details to an answer. I've added `draftState` and that's a copy of `state` in your `handleClick`.

Comment: Ohh! If I understand it correctly, its because I was modifying the songs object directly and I should be making a copy of it then calling setState with the copy

Comment: For the benifit of any future travelors, AWolf correctly stated the underlying issue. I had the same problem somewhere else and this fixed it there too. All of the comments and codeboxes provide very valuable best practice examples. Really appreciate everyones efforts with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into this https://codesandbox.io/embed/magical-leaf-hw8r4

I changed some minor stuff and put some comments there. It works for me. Iframe loading song in 1-2 s.

Comment: I am so grateful for the amount of effort you put into this response, with the insightful comments as well I really learned something. I really do appreciate it!

Comment: glad I could help :thumbsup: